# Python Autobahn websocket intermittent connection failures

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I have a website with a web page that makes secure (WSS) websocket connections to a given URL. The connection attempt is made from code in JavaScript. At that URL I have a python twisted server running that should accept the connection, do some processing, and return some data. Half the time it works fine. The problem is that often it doesn't. I used Firebug in Firefox to see what was happening, and it appears that the connection attempt to the websocket URL just seems to hang half the time.

As an example, I can go to the webpage in question and often it will work fine on the first attempt. If I then try to refresh the page, the page itself loads but the new connection to the websocket URL will often timeout. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it doesn't. Any idea how to debug or fix this? Does python Autobahn have any known intermittent connection issues?

Comment: There are no such issues known. You might try to enable debug output on the server by giving `debug = True` to your `WebSocketServerFactory` and watch what happens when a client connection attempt fails.